# 1980s sci-fi childrens' book series which taught programming in BASIC

Tags: story-identification, novel, childrens-novel

When I was a kid, I had this book about a group of people in a spaceship, looking for a material called "magnetite", as I recall. The cover had a generic sci-fi image of said vessel, which was obviously modeled after the USS Enterprise, flying through space.

At the back of the book was a complete computer program, written in BASIC, which the reader could copy into his computer to get a video game based on the story. The program code took up several pages. Apparently this book was one of a series, though I only ever saw the one volume.

Does anyone know what this might be?

Comment: Someone linked https://usborne.com/us/books/computer-and-coding-books in a similar question, but they look to be more instructional books than story ones.

Comment: Do you remember what flavour of BASIC it was or who the target market were? Was it aimed at ZX Spectrum owners or BBC Micro owners, for example?

Comment: @Valorum - I vaguely remember a similar book, and while I don't know dialects, I know it worked on an Apple II variant

Comment: https://blog.ldodds.com/2022/02/18/remembering-input-magazine/

Comment: Oh man, the feelz... I remember reading magazines/journals with printed code that you could hand type (spending hours correcting typos) to run the included programs. Now, you just clone a repo on GitHub and have insta-code...

Comment: I wonder if this might have been in one of the YA tech magazines (e.g., [*Enter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_(magazine)), etc.)? They often had sci-fi looking covers, and code for games inside was kinda a staple. I recall poetry and short fiction also appearing. "Quoth the Maven 'Robot War'"...

Comment: @Valorum Not sure about the "flavor" of BASIC, but I do know it was meant to be run on a Commodore 64, so ... "basic" BASIC?

Comment: This was definitely a paperback book, and not a magazine.

Comment: @FreeMan: I remember being so thrilled when Rainbow magazine introduced a checksum program that let you quickly check the typed code and find which line you got wrong.

Comment: Of course, you had to get the checksum code entered correctly... :rofl:

Comment: @bmurrell30 Commodore 64 BASIC is a specific flavor of BASIC; in the 80s, every microcomputer had its own version and programs were not typically compatible between them.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [Micro Adventure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Adventure) (1984)?

> Micro Adventure is the title of a series of books for young adult readers, published by Scholastic, Inc. during the 1980s. Created by Eileen Buckholtz and Ruth Glick, the YA series combined adventure stories with computer activities.
>
> The books are noted for the inclusion of short BASIC type-in programs related to the plot of the story that the reader could type into their computers, and also for the use of second-person narration (rather like the Choose Your Own Adventure series, though unlike those, Micro Adventure storylines could not be influenced by the decisions of the reader).

Comment: No, this isn't it. These books have several small programs at the end, and the one I'm remembering definitely had one large one.